# How to select and load specific set of images in a folder using Python?

Tags: python, image, selection

I have a folder comprising thousands of image files (all .jpg).  I want to select only a specific subset of these images and load them into my program for face recognition application.  I have the following code snippet for this process:

```
from PIL import Image
import os, os.path

images = []
path = "/path/to/images"
wanted_images = ["What goes in here?"]
for i in os.listdir(path):
    ext = os.path.splitext(i)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in wanted_images:
        continue
    images.append(Image.open(os.path.join(path,i)))
```

Is there a smart way to manage "What goes in here?" section of the code?  Essentially, the images are labeled "1_1.jpg",...,"1_20.jpg", "2_1.jpg",...,"2_20.jpg", "3_1.jpg",...,"3_20.jpg",...,"100_1.jpg",...,"100_20.jpg".  I want to select only images labeled "1_11.jpg", "2_11.jpg", "3_11.jpg", ...,"100_11.jpg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to open all images with a basename ending with '_11.jpg' you could do this:

```
from PIL import Image
from glob import glob
from os import path

directory = '<your directory>'

images = [Image.open(jpg) for jpg in glob(path.join(directory, '*_11.jpg'))]
```

Note that the pattern matching is case sensitive so it won't identify files ending, for example, in .JPG

Comment: Thank you for your time.  However, as I have remarked to the poster before you, I still get empty [] for images when I run your code.  Wonder what the bug is.

My apologies. Your code worked perfectly fine.  I had typed in "*-11.jpg" instead of the underscore.  My bad!  Thank you!

Comment: If my answer doesn't work for you then it's because there are no files ending with _11.jpg in the specified directory. Also worth noting that if the specified directory doesn't exist then glob will return nothing - i.e., that is not considered to be an exception

Comment: One last question:  how to convert the list "images" to a folder suitable for download? I am new to Python, so please excuse my ineptness.

Comment: @Nanda Please explain why you want to download files that are already on your filesystem

Comment: That's a good question.  I work on Google Colab.  The list "images" is stored in "variables", when I really wanted it in my "folders" tab.  

Also, I want to learn a few things about lists.  For instance, how to convert a list of objects into a directory, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work. [Glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) can help you select paths based on patterns. The builtin pathlib library supports glob patterns nicely.

```
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

images = []
path = "/path/to/images"
for p in Path(path).glob("**/*_11.jpg"):
    images.append(Image.open(str(p)))
```

Comment: `glob.glob()` also works if you don't care for Pathlib.

Comment: "images" return empty [].  Not sure if it reading the specified set of images.

Comment: Can't say why that would be without seeing your code, but try to make sure the right `path` is specified.

Comment: All I did was the following:

for p in glob.glob("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Kaggle/all_images/*_11.jpg"):
  images.append(Image.open(str(p)))

Comment: Code looks fine, maybe try a relative path?

Comment: "\*_11.jpg" is all you need - not "\*\*/\*_11.jpg" unless you want a recursive search in which case you need to specify *recursive=True*